# Ajax request encounters error 403 when using custom request class

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, http-status-code-403

I have created a custom request class to add validation rules for my form in a Laravel 5.2 application. But it accepts only normal post request and not allowing the ajax/post request (403 Response).

Laravel default request object accepts both normal post and ajax post. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: It's probably because of the CSRF token. Are you sending the CSRF token as part of your ajax request data? Please update your question with the request class code, ajax code, and probably, the error messages from the logs.

Comment: Ajax request requires authorize() method for custom request class. :(

Answer (score 1):

Its working after i added the authorize() method in to my custom request class.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#authorizing-form-requests